# How to give third party libraries in composer.json in Symfony 2.1 and access library in our bundle?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1, composer-php, packagist

I need to integrate [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/) as third party library in Symfony 2.1.

I tried in composer.json like

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "git://tcpdf.git.sourceforge.net/gitroot/tcpdf/tcpdf"
    }
],
"require": {
    "tcpdf/tcpdf":"*"
},
```

But it gives an error `The requested package tcpdf * could not be found.`

How to give third party libraries correct in composer.json file?

[TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/) library don't follow namespaces, so how we can access this library in our bundle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason it's not found is that the package name in the tcpdf repo is `tecnick.com/tcpdf`, so that's what you should require.

That said, since it's available [on packagist](http://packagist.org/packages/tecnick.com/tcpdf) you don't need to add the vcs repository at all in your composer.json.

Comment: Thanks. How we can directly access tcpdf lib in our custom bundle? How we can create a tcpdf instance in AppKernel?

Comment: `new TCPDF()` or whatever the classname is you want to instantiate should just work once the package is installed, it will be autoloadable.

Comment: When running this command `php composer.phar update`, `tecnick.com/tcpdf` is cloned. After that it waits for some time without showing anything in command prompt and display an error message `[RuntimeException]  The process timed out.`   
I have added `new TCPDF()` in AppKernel, but it gives me an error `Class 'TCPDF' not found`. I  edited file `/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php` and added a line `require $vendorDir . '/tecnick.com/tcpdf/tcpdf.php';` . It gives me an error `Call to undefined method TCPDF::getName()`.  So I think autoload is not worked correctly.

Comment: That looks like it timed out and did not finish the clone.. Try again and maybe also look into changing the process-timeout setting if you have a slow connection, see http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#config

Comment: I don't know what is happening, after increasing process-timeout setting to 1000, same error persists. Please check  my [composer.json and error in console](http://pastebin.com/b3LN1zHJ)

Answer (score 0):

There are [several packages](http://packagist.org/search/?q=tcpdf) related to TCPDF on [Packagist](http://packagist.org/) — some of them are bundles to integrate it with Symfony.

Comment: I am looking for bundle supports symfony version `2.1`. But I don't see anything perfect for this.

Comment: I use "tcpdf/tcpdf": "dev-master" in my composer.json. In my app/autoload.php: require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/tcpdf/tcpdf/tcpdf.php'; Then I wrote an own Helper class that extends \ TCPDF. It works.

Answer (score -1):

Since tcpdf does not support composer you need to use the package repository. The docs for this is available at:

http://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#package-2

Do note that their example configuration has both `dist` and `source` where `source` is what you need. You will probably also need to configure the autoloading to match that of tcpdf. You can find documentation on that on the composer website as well.

A good thing would also be to send the tcpdf authors an email and ask them if they don't mind adding a composer.json.

Comment: TCPDF supports composer since 5.9.181 (2012-08-31)